# spring sleuth - difference between tag and baggage

Tags: java, spring

I was looking for information on Spring Sleuth and additional fields such as tag and baggage and I'm a bit confused. I knew that tag is related with spanId and baggage is releted with traceId. 
But I can't understand how I should correct propagete new tags and baggages...

1) I found that tag can add this way `span.tag("aaaaaa", "bbbbbb");`, but how I can add baggage ?

2) What is ExtraFieldPropagation class ? I can i easy way add and get new field. I see this information in headers. But what is this? baggage or tag ?

3) Is way to add same extra fields to span context and later get this information but that this information should not be included in the headers ?